# UITableView Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to use a UITableView by implementing the code I saw on many tutorials but it doesn't work correctly when I run it. What am I doing wrong? I added a cell to the view and added a corresponding identifier. [My storyboard look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YP7d.png)
and code is the following:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var data = ["m","2","3"]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableV: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableV.delegate = self
        tableV.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell = tableV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}
```

And
[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7gLN.png).
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This code looks good. Could you please me where do you see problem?

Comment: Please check whether you have given "PostCell" as your cell identifier in story board.

Comment: what does that mean _"but it doesn't work correctly when I run it"_? you have 3 items on your _model_, and all 3 items appear correctly in your tableview; what is the issue here?

Comment: Click on the “what it looks like” link to the image of the simulator.

Comment: @ParthPatel I see a screenshot from simulator. There are 3 rows with labels "m", "2" and "3". Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this way to correct errors.

change this:

`let cell = tableV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")`

with:

`let cell = tableV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath)`

and you need to check cell identifier.